# How to refresh the GridView in onSelectedIndexChanged() of a drop down?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How to refresh the `GridView` in `onSelectIndexChange` of a drop down ?
I want the grid to be refreshed or cleared on every index change 
and when the `ddlist.selectvalue=0` then a pop up comes saying `Please select valid option` and then the grid hides.

I am using this code:

```
 Protected Sub ddllist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddllist.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ddllist.SelectedValue = 1 Then

            tdtype.InnerHtml = "Leas ID"
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            trtype.Visible = True

        ElseIf (ddllist.SelectedValue = 0) Then
            btnSave.Enabled = False
            trtype.Visible = False
            ' Gridconten.DataSource = ""
            'Gridconten.DataBind()
            'Page_Load(sender, e)
            Gridconten.DataSource = Nothing
            Gridconten.DataBind()

        Else
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            tdtype.InnerHtml = "Vendor ID"
            trtype.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code that is used to bind the `Gridconten`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ok i have got it after some try i am using this !!
>   basically i am binding it with no data and hiding the grid on index
>   change

```
 Protected Sub ddllist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddllist.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ddllist.SelectedValue = 1 Then
            Label2.Text = ""
            tdtype.InnerHtml = "Leas ID"
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            trtype.Visible = True
            Gridconten.DataSource = Nothing
            Gridconten.DataBind()
            Gridconten.Visible = False
            Gridconten.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Lease ID"

        ElseIf (ddllist.SelectedValue = 0) Then
            btnSave.Enabled = False
            trtype.Visible = False
            Label2.Text = ""
            ' Gridconten.DataSource = ""
            'Gridconten.DataBind()
            'Page_Load(sender, e)
            Gridconten.DataSource = Nothing
            Gridconten.DataBind()

            Gridconten.Visible = False

        Else
            Label2.Text = ""
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            tdtype.InnerHtml = "Vendor ID"
            trtype.Visible = True
            Gridconten.DataSource = Nothing  
            Gridconten.DataBind()            
            Gridconten.Visible = False
            Gridconten.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Vendor ID"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like it clears the gridview and hides it no matter what option is chosen.